# PUT is broken when I define method before save, in loopback

Tags: post, put, loopbackjs

I try to change some field when I create/update data whith loopback. The POST method works, but now the PUT method is down.

my category.json:

```
{
 "name": "category",
 "base": "PersistedModel",
 "properties": {
   "name": {
     "type": "string",
     "required": true
   },
   "image": {
     "type": "string",
     "required": true
   }
 },
 "validations": [],
 "relations": {},
 "acls": [],
 "methods": []
}
```

and the category.js for define methods:

```
module.exports = function(categorie) {

  categorie.observe('before save', function(ctx, next){

    ctx.instance.name = ctx.instance.name.toUpperCase().trim();
    ctx.instance.image = ctx.instance.image.trim();
    ctx.instance.image = ctx.instance.image.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ctx.instance.image.slice(1);

    next();
  });
};
```

I receive this error message:

{
  "error": {
    "name": "TypeError",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined",
    "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined\n    at /home/pitt/warm-wildwood-2324/common/models/category.js:5:35\n    at notifySingleObserver (/home/pitt/warm-wildwood-2324/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model.js:600:22)\n   (...)    at Function.ModelBaseClass.notifyObserversOf (/home/pitt/warm-wildwood-2324/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model.js:593:8)"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.instance` is not undefined while partial update of possibly multiple models, instead access `ctx.data` property.

check the [docs](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks)